# Кодировка передаваемых данных

Tags: кодировка, irc, java

Итак. Начну. 4 части.

**1**. **Сервер**

Есть сервер. Он принимает данные от клиентов, логирует и потом эти данные забирает плагин.
*В логах и в консоли русские символы отображаются как "????? ??? ??"*

**2**. **Клиенты**

Есть некая программа, которая на русский язык не расчитана. Русифицирована просто заменой символов "ýòî êàêîé-òî òåêñò, ïðèâåò ñåðâåð!" на "это какой-то текст, привет сервер!". Ну в общем тупо одни символы заменяются другими.
Пример: Клиент1 отсылает серверу сообщение. Клиент видит сообщение как "сообщение1", но серверу отсылается "ñîîáùåíèå1". Сервер с этим работает и высылает другим клиентам "ñîîáùåíèå1". Ну а клиент2 видит "сообщение1", хотя получает "ñîîáùåíèå1".

**3**. **IRC-чат**

При помощи плагина(о нём ниже), данные, которые передают клиенты, IRC-бот пишет на канал.
В ирц латинские символы нормально отображается. Русские как "????? ??? ??".

**4**. **Плагин**

Плагин включает в себя IRC-бота. При получении сервером сообщения, ирцбот пишет сообщение на канал.

**В чём проблема?**
На IRC-канале русские буквы отображаются знаками вопроса.
Пробовал перекодировать. Даже тупо заменить одни буквы на другие(как и в клиенте). Не помогло. Вывод - плагин получает данные уже в виде ??? ????? ??.

Нужно исправить. В Java я программирую всего неделю, но за счёт схожести синтакса Java и C++, я быстренько разобрался. Если вам не сложно, набросайте уже готовый код, а я попробую разобраться.

И ещё. Декодером кодировка определилась как cp1252. Но на форумах данного продукта говорят, что ASCII.

Comment: <offtopic>Странно, что после стольких усилий по интернационализации Java, возникают таки проблемы.</offtopic>. Клиенты написаны не на Java? Какие этапы передачи сообщения вы можете изменить? Я бы для начала убрал эту аццкую замену символов - вы же должны понимать, что то, как символы отображаются  зависит не только от того, что хранится внутри, но также от того, как это содержимое трактуется. Другими словами, не нужно менять контент сообщений - нужно менять (или, скорее, приводить в единство) то, в какой кодировке сообщения читаются.

Comment: Клиенты я заменить не могу. Потому что клиентов много, люди случайные и интернеты разные. А в интернет уже выпущена версия русификатора и всё качают её. Как вы уже поняли, мой русификатор и старый будут несовместимы. Я могу изменить сервер, IRC-бота и плагин.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что в скриптах надо смотреть, какая кодировка там прописана. И ставить ту, которую вам надо. У вас по ходу действия получается, что скрипт рассчитывает на UTF8, а сервер настроен на 1251 или 1252 по умолчанию (и как ни странно, в скрипте почему-то хедера нет, который показывает кодировку). Так что можно просто серверу указать, что вся работа будет вестись в UTF8 и не мучать скрипты переделками.

Answer (score 1):

А какая кодировка определяется, как cp1252?

В любом случае выбор у вас невелик - сначала смотрите, в какой кодировке клиенты отсылают сообщения (т.е. в какой кодировке находятся символы, которыми заменяются кракозябры); то, что "в логах и в консоли русские символы отображаются как "????? ??? ??"" говорит лишь о том, что вы просматриваете логи и консоль не с той кодировкой - поэкспериментируйте. Дальше зависит от того, как это все дело у вас взаимодействует. Если сервер, плагин и бот написаны на Java - то останется только на сервере формировать правильные строки (все строки в Java - в Unicode): например, если данные от клиента приходят в виде массива байт, то используя [такой конструктор](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29). Кроме того, нужно удостовериться, чего ждет от вас IRC-канал: отправить данные в нужной кодировке можно [этим методом](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29). Для перекодировок можно обойтись и без строк: использовать [CharsetDecoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) и [CharsetEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) в связке, например.